# Dice problem, with image explanation.

Tags: probability, dice

Four dice are rolled SIMULTANEOUSLY. $X_1$ is a random variable that represents how many 1's you get in a single roll. $X_2, ... , X_4$ are defined in the same fashion, like in the picture below. [image]

Remember the rolls are NOT consecutive. Let Y = $X_1X_2X_3X_4$. What values Y can get? Get $E(Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y$ takes the values $0$ and $1$, the latter if and only if you have one each of $1,2,3$ and $4$, which occurs with probability $4!/6^4=1/54$, which is thus the value of $E(Y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The variable $Y=0$ unless your four numbers are exactly $1,2,3,4$ in some order.  In that case $Y=1$, because $X_1=X_2=X_3=X_4=1$.

Comment: If each random variable can vary between 0,1,2,3 and 4 why did you assume they're all equal to one? Wouldn't the expected value of Y be the multiplication of each variable?

Comment: @matt_zarro, the variables are not independent.  If any one of them takes a value greater than $1$, then one of the others must take the value $0$, which makes their product $Y=0$.  (Oh, I answered this in part because I thought it was a comment to my answer!)

Comment: eureka!!!!! Thanks so much @BarryCipra !! Finally it makes sense, math is so beautiful!

Comment: Thanks to you too @vadim123 for the fast answer, but barry's also answered the expected value, wish i could mark both as wright..